# jdbc - sql server not showing any output / error in the console

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to sql server 2005 from my Java application using

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://servername\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "database=master";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl);
        System.out.println("Connected to SQL Server");
        String sql = "select * from employee";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

On executing it, I do not get any output  / error at the console. What am I missing?

Comment: Your query probably don't have any results, or you may be executing it on the wrong database...

Comment: The database is master and the employee table has records in it.

Comment: The connection URL doesn't have the credentials. Did you leave them intentionally or is this your exact code snippet? anyways, you may want to check http://vikdor.blogspot.com/2012/10/connecting-to-sql-server-express.html for connecting to SQL Server Express using JDBC which is slightly different from connection to a normal SQL Server instance.

Comment: debug your program. Either use a good IDE, or Use System.out after createStatement and executeQuery. This will ensure what Thihara mentioned above. Most probably your query is not returning any data.

Comment: It is using windows authentication for SQL Server, hence I have omitted the username and password. My console is not displaying any output. It is not restricted to this program.

Comment: You mean you program don't display System.out.println out puts to your console? Which IDE are you using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is no records in the table employee.
Or it throws an Exception whose e.getMessage() returns ""(I don't think so,but to avoid it,You can use e.printStackTrace() instead).

Answer (score 0):

actually,the correct answer is...

when you insert the record in sql prompt we have to commit that record by command commit;
sql>commit;

even thought when you insert the record after that you can check by command select *from table;

record is inserted successfully...record is there

but in command prompt when we executing java program records are not displaying....

so commit the record when u inserted..

thankyou